# POST method in objective-C and PHP

Tags: php, objective-c

I have created the following POST method via objective-C

```
-(IBAction) postLocation: (id) sender{
 NSString *latitude = @"37.3229978"; 
 NSString *longitude = @"-122.0321823";

 NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomain.me/webservice.php"]];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"latitude=%@longitude=%@submit",latitude,longitude];
 [request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *err;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
        }
```

and my PHP code is:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']){

  //it doesn't get into this if statement
  $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
  $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];

}
```

The question is, why can't the PHP code get into the if statement? Where can I state the 'submit' through objective-C?

Comment: did u ever find an answer?  I am having this exact problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110180/php-get-value-erased-when-placed-in-ifisset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query string for the `POST` does not contain the `submit` key. You should change it to the following

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"latitude=%@&longitude=%@&submit=",latitude,longitude];
```

Comment: apparently it still does nothing.... how can I check in my PHP code that it actually triggers the code inside the if statement?

Comment: You could write to a log from the PHP file to validate the call and action.

Comment: okay, I did try an error log, and it doesn't create it as it doesn't get into the if statement even after the modification above... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should log before if clause, in the if clause, and log `$_POST` as well. That should give you a clear picture of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

No "&"s between the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction) postLocation: (id) sender{

    NSString *latitude = @"37.3229978"; 
    NSString *longitude = @"-122.0321823";

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&latitude=%@&longitude=%@", latitude, longitude];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSString *address_url = @"http://www.mydomain.me/webservice.php?";

    address_url = [address stringByAppendingString:post];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:address]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it is simpler to use `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` instead of the code that you have now to check for form post.