# php $_GET value erased when placed in if(!isset)

Tags: php, get

This works fine:

```
$username= $_GET["username"];
$query= "INSERT INTO test (latitude) VALUES ('$username')";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error"));
mysql_close();
```

This does not work:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
}
else
{
$username= $_GET["username"];
$query= "INSERT INTO test (latitude) VALUES ('$username')";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error"));
mysql_close();
}
```

It works if $username is set to something other than get, like '7'.

The GET retrieving a value from objective c.  If I don't put it in an if statement it will just enter itself into my database hundreds of times.  If I put it in the 'if' statement it will only enter once, but the value will be zero.  I'm totally stumped.  Any help would be great.

EDIT:
I think because of the answers I'm getting that i didn't explain well.  to clarify:  I am using POST to post user_id, answer_body.  I am using GET as a way to import the latitude and longitude from Core Location (even though I named it username, it is the latitude). I want them all to go into the same entry, which is why im tying GET to isset_POST.  Further, when GET(username) is on its own, with an INSERT query, it will make hundreds of duplicates in my database.  Here is the objective-C script:

```
//sends whatever username is set to, to database
float username = location.coordinate.latitude;
NSString *theValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", username];
NSString *hostStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysite.com/page.php?username=%@", theValue];
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Server output: %@", serverOutput);
```

The form code is:

```
<form action="gpstestertwo.php" method="post"><center>
                $<input type="text" name="answer_body" maxlentgh= "5"  style="height:3em;"/>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" style="height:2em; width:5em; font-size:19px " 
                 />
                 </center>
            </form>
```

Comment: SQL injection beware. When you POST, are you actually sending the username as a POST field, or a GET field?

Comment: `var_dump($_GET)`, `var_dump($_POST)` - what do you get?

Comment: cbuckley- I'm sending something completely different as the POST, im only using the if isset POST in order to insert the get variable into the same entry as the form fields.  Does that make sense?

Comment: jan267- im kinda new, but I think that people hacking into databases all over the place is a myth.  deceze: when I do var_dump(get) it returns array(0) { }, when I do var dump post i get array(2) { ["answer_body"]=> string(1) "3" ["submit"]=> string(6) "submit" }.  thanks guys.

Comment: So there is no GET query parameter in the URL...?!?! Also, *always* escape data, regardless of attacks or not. You're simply making sure your syntax is valid! [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['submit']` and `$_GET['username']`... why not use `$_POST['username']`.

How are you sending the `FORM` data, `POST` or `GET`? Or use `$_REQUEST['username']` to be sure.

**Not to mention the need to escape the username before using in query.**

**EDIT** (always do the processing on `POSTs`, not `GETs`):

```
if(!strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST')){
    // post operation, do your work HERE only
    if(!empty($_POST['username'])){
        // ... do your worst here ...
    }
}
```

`GETs` are the default request and you might end up bombarded in your database. `POSTs` are the special ones. So make sure the `REQUEST_METHOD` is `POST` before doing `POST` handling.

Comment: Well, I DID try If ISSET $Get_Username, and that kept the value intact, but the problem was it inserted like a hundred duplicates.  The form is being sent POST but the data that keeps being entered as zero is a GET from objective c NSURL.

Comment: @Celeste You need to do your query only when a POST occurs. See my edits in a minute.

Comment: Hey Claudrian, it's still inserting zeros.  Although, based on ur answer I was able to confirm that changing the code to POST_username instead of GET_username works, as long as it is not in an if(isset statement.  But it still inserts hundreds of duplicates.  Could the issue be that php cannot retrieve from objective c while inside of an if statement?  Does that make any sense?

Comment: @Celeste I don't know how the two inter-operate. Can't help you with that. I know PHP and C++ :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$username= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["username"]);
$query= "INSERT INTO test (latitude) VALUES ('$username')";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error"));
mysql_close();
}
```

EDIT:
First, I changed the $_GET and the $_POST to $_REQUEST so it will accept both $_GET and $_POST.

Second, I added the `mysql_real_escape_string` function, that will escape unwanted chars such as qutation marks, in order to prevent SQL Injection.